# Can't play video from URL using AVPlayer, Error: NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avplayer

I have used a library https://github.com/VeinGuo/VGPlayer to play video in my custom view. But I faced error

> Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-2), NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed, NSUnderlyingError=0x281933e40 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-2 "(null)"}}

I have just implemented ***Embed in cell of tableView*** in my project from GitHub example. For getting error reason I have just created new empty project and do same thing in that and I just shocked It is working fine in that (Same device, same xcode). I have researched lot of but I couldn't found what is actual problem in my project. Please help me!

I have used [this](https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/gymstar-app/7A77786B4870594D7165625046614E74/post_videos/postVideo1582781434.005436.mp4) url for playing video. It is working fine in my new project but not in my actual project.

Below is the `addPlayer` method from `VGEmbedTableViewController` file. and other code is same as gitHub repository's example. I have only changed url.

```
    func addPlayer(_ cell: UITableViewCell) {
    if player != nil {
        player.cleanPlayer()
    }
    configurePlayer()
    cell.contentView.addSubview(player.displayView)
    player.displayView.snp.makeConstraints {
        $0.edges.equalTo(cell)
    }
    player.replaceVideo(URL(string:"https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/gymstar-app/7A77786B4870594D7165625046614E74/post_videos/postVideo1582781434.005436.mp4")!)
    player.play()
}
```

Comment: Instead of using a 3rd party, why don't you simply use `AVPlayer` to get the video playing?

Comment: @PGDev Because I need custom view. Please help me why I faced this issue.

Comment: You can then add `AVPlayerLayer` to your custom view.

Comment: Okay, I will implement default `AVPlayer`. But I want to know about my issue. You can see in `VGPlayer` They are simple play with `AVPlayer`, nothing extra. Then why I got error? @PGDev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue is solved by clearing cache which are saved by `VGPlayer` library. They provides methods for clear cache and delete files,

```
    open func cleanAllCache() {
    ioQueue.sync {
        do {
            let cacheDirectory = VGPlayerCacheManager.cacheDirectory()
            try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: cacheDirectory)
        } catch { }
    }
}

open func cleanOldFiles(completion handler: (()->())? = nil) {
    ioQueue.sync {
        let cacheDirectory = VGPlayerCacheManager.cacheDirectory()
        var (URLsToDelete, diskCacheSize, cachedFiles) = self.cachedFiles(atPath: cacheDirectory, onlyForCacheSize: false)

        for fileURL in URLsToDelete {
            do {
                try fileManager.removeItem(at: fileURL)
            } catch _ { }
        }

        if cacheConfig.maxCacheSize > 0 && diskCacheSize > cacheConfig.maxCacheSize {
            let targetSize = cacheConfig.maxCacheSize / 2

            let sortedFiles = cachedFiles.keysSortedByValue {
                resourceValue1, resourceValue2 -> Bool in

                if let date1 = resourceValue1.contentAccessDate,
                    let date2 = resourceValue2.contentAccessDate
                {
                    return date1.compare(date2) == .orderedAscending
                }

                return true
            }

            for fileURL in sortedFiles {
                let (_, cacheSize, _) = self.cachedFiles(atPath: fileURL.path, onlyForCacheSize: true)
                diskCacheSize -= cacheSize

                do {
                    try fileManager.removeItem(at: fileURL)
                } catch { }

                URLsToDelete.append(fileURL)

                if diskCacheSize < targetSize {
                    break
                }
            }
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            if URLsToDelete.count != 0 {
                let cleanedHashes = URLsToDelete.map { $0.lastPathComponent }
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .VGPlayerCacheManagerDidCleanCache, object: self, userInfo: [VGPlayerCacheManager.VGPlayerCleanCacheKey: cleanedHashes])
            }

            handler?()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the simple swift code to play the content.

```
func play() {
    // Get AVPlayerItem


    let url = URL(string:"https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/gymstar-app/7A77786B4870594D7165625046614E74/post_videos/postVideo1582781434.005436.mp4")


    //let url = URL(string:"http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8")



    self.asset = AVURLAsset(url: url!)
    self.playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset!)

    // Get AVPlayer
    self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: self.playerItem)

    self.playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    self.playerViewController!.player = self.player;

    self.present(self.playerViewController!, animated: true) {
        self.player?.play()
    }
}
```